# Using query but it returns a null row? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a number of values. However, when I use the command:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id <= 2 AND id IS NOT NULL
```

I get the following output:

```
#  id
1  1
2  2
*  NULL
```

However, having this NULL row messes up things, as I would like to use a IN statement on this subquery, which evaluates to FALSE as there is a comparison with a NULL value.

Could someone explain why this NULL value exists, and how to get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you `use the command`? Within the console? Or in some other tool? What's `#` and `*` mean? It's not how the results are presented by mysql shell, I mean.

Comment: what does the `*` to the left of `NULL` mean?

Comment: Please run `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '*'`, does it show any result ?